# Using Google Cloud API python sample asynchronous recording code is giving me attribute error

Tags: python, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

Link to code:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/transcribe_async.py

I'm using the sample python code from Google Speech API to convert long (greater than 1 minute) audio files from speech to text. How do I run the code in PyCharm so it converts my audio file (in wave format) to text using the API key I created (to charge my account) without getting the 'NoneType' error?

I added the path of the audio file directly into the code (line 73). I also added "--" in front of 'path' to make it process the LOC (line 73). The error I get is as follows:

```
**C:\Users\Dave\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/mizu/gcapi.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/mizu/gcapi.py", line 75, in <module>
    if args.path.startswith('gs://'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
Process finished with exit code1**


import argparse
import io


# [START speech_transcribe_async]
def transcribe_file(speech_file):
    """Transcribe the given audio file asynchronously."""
    from google.cloud import speech
    from google.cloud.speech import enums
    from google.cloud.speech import types
    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    # [START speech_python_migration_async_request]
    with io.open(speech_file, 'rb') as audio_file:
        content = audio_file.read()

    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)
    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code='en-US')

    # [START speech_python_migration_async_response]
    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)
    # [END speech_python_migration_async_request]

    print('Waiting for operation to complete...')
    response = operation.result(timeout=90)

    # Each result is for a consecutive portion of the audio. Iterate through
    # them to get the transcripts for the entire audio file.
    for result in response.results:
        # The first alternative is the most likely one for this portion.
        print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
        print('Confidence: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].confidence))
    # [END speech_python_migration_async_response]
# [END speech_transcribe_async]


# [START speech_transcribe_async_gcs]
def transcribe_gcs(gcs_uri):
    """Asynchronously transcribes the audio file specified by the gcs_uri."""
    from google.cloud import speech
    from google.cloud.speech import enums
    from google.cloud.speech import types
    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)
    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
        sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code='en-US')

    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)

    print('Waiting for operation to complete...')
    response = operation.result(timeout=90)

    # Each result is for a consecutive portion of the audio. Iterate through
    # them to get the transcripts for the entire audio file.
    for result in response.results:
        # The first alternative is the most likely one for this portion.
        print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
        print('Confidence: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].confidence))
# [END speech_transcribe_async_gcs]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument(
        '--path', help='C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/mizu/output.wav')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.path.startswith('gs://'):
        transcribe_gcs(args.path)
    else:
        transcribe_file(args.path)
```

I expect it to output a file with text from the audio file being transcribed, billing my account in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

With `parser.add_argument('--path', help='C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/mizu/output.wav')` you just defined that your script may accept argument `--path` after it's invoked from command line, and that text is just a help text shown if someone starts your script with `--help` argument.

So, if that script where `if __name__ == '__main__'` is located has the name myscript.py, you actually have to start your script like:

```
python myscript.py --path C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/mizu/output.wav
```

But, that routine makes no sense in this case, a solution for you is to get rid of that extra code. Do just:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    transcribe_file('C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/mizu/output.wav')
```

Comment: I changed line 73 to what you suggested, but I get the error: "gcapi.py: error: the following arguments are required: python gcapi.py --path, C:/Users/Dave/Desktop/mizu/output.wav"

Comment: I think that did it. I uhm, didn't define credentials though.  So I'm going to figure out how to do that. Because that's the only problem it seems like here on out. While you're here.. You wouldn't happen to know how to do determine credentials would you?

Comment: There's a link in [Readme](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/README.rst#authentication).